# S3 get metadata of older version objects

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda, aws-java-sdk

I am getting a 405 method not allowed while trying to retrieve metadata of older versions of an S3 object using a Lambda Java function.

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = getAmazonS3();
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, templateKey, versionId);
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = amazonS3.getObject(getObjectRequest).getObjectMetadata(); // Exception thrown at this line

public AmazonS3 getAmazonS3() {
    String region = PropertyManager.getValue(PropertyKey.AWS_REGION.getKey(stage));
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region)
                .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()).build();
    }
```

Stack trace in Lambda:

```
    The specified method is not allowed against this resource. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 405; Error Code: MethodNotAllowed; Request ID: 1D12DDA5F0493282): com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified method is not allowed against this resource. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 405; Error Code: MethodNotAllowed; Request ID: 1D12DDA5F0493282), S3 Extended Request ID: jTNnAl8ifgsUlPMV0GEHAEVBtWwjTprEJy45C9BMJ5kTk/Qn8Pne8/ZM/tH27ZoeUtHrd1NeuyQ=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1588)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4187)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4134)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1385)
    at com.ghx.templateengine.template.GetTemplateVersions.handleRequest(GetTemplateVersions.java:66)
```

Comment: Do you get the same exception when trying to fetch the object itself and not its metadata ?

Comment: I am able to fetch the object when not specifying the versionId. If I specify then I get a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

A few of the older versions of the S3 object had **delete marker**. AWS support conveyed that trying to head object a version that is a delete marker results in a 405 error.